# dynamic input html jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I have some problem with my dynamic input, I want to add and delete the input but when I try to delete, the action delete the view that does not match with the view position, for example
let's say I have a list like this

- input1
- input2

when I tried to delete input2 instead input1 deleted

My approach

**html**

```
<div class="row" id="list-barang-dipilih">
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#tambah-barang').click(() => {
    var idBarang = $('#option-barang option:selected').val()
    var namaBarang = $('#option-barang option:selected').text().trim()
    var jumlahBarang = $('#jumlah-barang').val()
    var htmlElement = '<div class="col-md-12" id="barang-baru">'+
    '<div class="col-md-6">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama-barang-dipilih" name="nama_barang" placeholder="Nama barang" value="${namaBarang}" readonly>`+
            `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id-barang-dipilih" name="id_barang" placeholder="id_barang" value="${idBarang}" readonly>`+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-4">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="jumlah-barang-dipilih" name="jumlah_barang" placeholder="Jumlah item.." value="${jumlahBarang}" readonly>`+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">'+
                '<span aria-hidden="true" id="hapus-barang">&times;</span>'+
            '</button>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>'
    $('#list-barang-dipilih').append(
        htmlElement
    )
})


$(document).on('click', '#hapus-barang', ()=>{ 
    $('#barang-baru').remove()
})
```

so the id="tambah-barang" for add the field and id="hapus-barang" for remove field

also after the input is added and user fill the input, I want to get all the data from all input

Comment: so.. just to be sure, are the `input2` and `input1` shares the same `id`? if so, thats where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve the problem, i just add the index to the wrapper when I append the view

so it become like this

```
const listItem = () => { 
var i = 0;
$('#tambah-barang').click(() => {
    i++;
    var idBarang = $('#option-barang option:selected').val()
    var namaBarang = $('#option-barang option:selected').text().trim()
    var jumlahBarang = $('#jumlah-barang').val()
    var htmlElement = `<div class="col-md-12" id="barang-baru-${i}">`+
    '<div class="col-md-6">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama-barang-dipilih" name="nama_barang" placeholder="Nama barang" value="${namaBarang}" readonly>`+
            `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id-barang-dipilih" name="id_barang" placeholder="id_barang" value="${idBarang}" readonly>`+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-4">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="jumlah-barang-dipilih" name="jumlah_barang" placeholder="Jumlah item.." value="${jumlahBarang}" readonly>`+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">'+
                `<span aria-hidden="true" id="hapus-barang" onClick="onRemoveItem(${i})">&times;</span>`+
            '</button>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>'
    
    $('#list-barang-dipilih').append(
        htmlElement
    )
})


$('#save-transaksi').click(() => { 
    $('input[id^="nama-barang-dipilih"]').each((input) =>{ 
        var value1 = $('input[id^="nama-barang-dipilih"]').val()
        console.log(value1)
    })
})
```

}

function onRemoveItem(i) {
$(document).on('click', '#hapus-barang', ()=>{
$(`#barang-baru-${i}`).remove()
})
}